# Getting the number pixels in width and height inside an UI Object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, object, pixel

Currently I do something that looks a bit fuzzy because I am dealing with points with my UI Object but what I want to do is get the width and height of the UI Object (in my case a UIImageView) in pixels.

Is this possible? I have looked around the documentation but I have not seen anything that looks relevant.

Can anyone assist with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

`[object frame].size.height`

`[object frame].size.width`

I'm pretty sure that anything with a visual representation will have a frame attribute to indicate where it's located. Of course, the `origin` of an object's frame is relative to its container, but the `size` should always be useable.

Edit/Update:

I misread the initial question, which wants to also convert points --> pixels. Here's how to make sure you get that correctly:

```
float scale;
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    // This message was implemented in iOS 4.0
    scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
} else {
    // Anything that is running < 4.0 doesn't have a Retina display
    scale = 1.0;
}
```

Then, multiply the height and width values by scale to get actual pixel count.

Comment: +1. What I ended up doing is getting those points then multiplying it by the scale returned by UIScreen. You should edit your answer to include that so it doesn't confuse others.